# Изменение значения ссылки на себя

Tags: javascript, объекты

Как можно изменить значение объекта JavaScript?
Имею в виду я следующее...
К примеру, мы имеем :

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
a.foo();
a; // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Как я понимаю, нам нужно изменить `this` у объекта "массив"?
Подскажите пожалуйста, каким способом можно это сделать или литературу, где почитать? :)

Comment: в смысле вы хотите добавить к массиву функцию путем смены его "класса" ?

подойдет 

    a=new MyArr(a);
    a.foo(); 

?

Comment: мысли были скорее об этом: Array.prototype.foo = function() {...};

Comment: Так зачем дело стало? 
`Array.prototype.foo=function(){this.push(6)} //`

Comment: лучше не делать так. на то есть тонны причин.